# Проблема с подключением к БД MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть такая проблема, при отправки данных в базу данных, непонятно какого типа данных, и программа падает и пишет: `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"`.
Код:

```
    class MSQL
    {
        public string login;
        public string password;
        private string aut;
        public void conection()
        {
            string CommandText = "select name from new_table where name='" + login +"AND password='"+ password + "'";
            string Connect = "Database=new_schema;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConnect = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
            myConnect.Open();
            MySqlCommand myCommnd = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnect);
               string aut = myCommnd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            myConnect.Close();
            if (aut != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: у вас `login` не обернут одинарными кавычками, то-есть есть только 1на кавычка спереди, получаеться `'login`, а должно быть `'login'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте таким образом:

```
class MSQL
{
    public string login;
    public string password;
    private string aut;
    public void conection()
    {
        string CommandText = "SELECT name FROM new_table WHERE name='" + login +"'AND password='"+ password + "'";
        string Connect = "server=localhost;username=root;database=new_schema;password=root"; 
        MySqlConnection myConnect = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
        myConnect.Open();
        MySqlCommand myCommnd = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnect);
       try
{
        string aut = myCommnd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(aut); ///поправил
        myConnect.Close();       
}
        catch (Exception ex) 
         {
          MessageBox.Show("Ошибка у нас такая:    " + ex.Message);
         }
```

Должно работать. Проблема действительно с кавычками.